# How can I find out about the average vote count for questions and answers on a particular site?

Tags: feature-request, voting

Can I find out about the average vote count for questions and answers on a particular site?

If so, how?

What about the average vote count for my own questions/answers on a specific site?

Comment: You could certainly get that information from [the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).  Have you tried that?

Comment: @blahdiblah Thanks for pointing me to this; I think [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/95438/average-question-score) does it for questions on TeX.SE; not sure about answers.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for the 'Switch sites' feature underneath "Run Query".

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in single post.

Comment: @hims056 The question title as it stands was/is ambiguous, which wasn't initially obvious to me, but I think it may be better that way. You really think it's better to ask 4 separate questions instead, given that this one has no upvotes as of right now? And given that the answer queries are likely related or derivable from each other? And given that these questions are very much related? And given that the Data Explorer seems to have no way of requesting queries from those familiar with it?

Comment: @blahdiblah Actually, I was looking for an answer for TeX.SE specifically, so I had figured this one out; thanks anyways. // I noticed however that the site's queries are often not well-described. // See also my question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query to get you started:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/100124/average-question-and-answer-scores

(Hit edit query and then run)

```
AverageQuestionScore 
-------------------- 
1.54381662953265     
  
AverageAnswerScore 
------------------ 
1.96298005827769
```

You can modify the filters, for example, to remove closed questions.

To get a particular user's average question score and average answer score for a site, the following query does the job:

https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/100317/average-question-and-answer-scores-for-my-questions-and-answers

You can run these queries on other sites by using the "switch site" function on data.se

Comment: Awesome; as for the "my own questions and answers" part, I have tried this: http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/100317/  Not sure whether this works. For non-zero answers this seems to work, but for questions I definitely don't get the right results.

Comment: Your query works for me, but only on sites where I have questions and answers. Your link goes to the TEX stackexchange site, and I get blanks for that.

Comment: I thought so, but I most likely miscounted earlier. When I tested again just now, with users with a small number of questions/answers including at least one zero-score question/answer, the results were exactly right.

Comment: Huh. If I try it with my own score on this site (the big meta), I get the wrong result for my "my questions and answers" query: Right now I get 6 (for questions) and 0 (for answers), but the question score should be one of {27/6, 27/7, 29/7} (reflecting the progression of recent changes); I tried with my meta user ID, 188174.

Comment: Keep in mind that the data that you are querying against may be old. For example, last I checked, the stackoverflow.com data snapshot was from 2/03/13

Comment: So the date of the snapshot is given by the last data column in the [overview on the big site](http://data.stackexchange.com/). Mystery resolved!